# What's an appropriate way to express nostalgia in first person

Tags: expressions

Would saying it like this be okay?

> Feeling a bit nostalgia. Can't wait for another trip to Cali.

Or would *nostalgic* be a bit more acceptable?

Comment: "A bit nostalgic" or "a bit of nostalgia".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be either *feeling a bit **nostalgic*** or *feeling a bit **of** nostalgia*.

Nostalgia is a mass noun, so you can feel it or some of it.

> ***[nostalgia](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nostalgia)***
>
> NOUN
>
> *[mass noun]*
>    1.  A sentimental longing or wistful affection for a period in the past.
>        *‘I was overcome with acute nostalgia for my days at university’*

Whereas nostalgic is an adjective:

> ***[nostalgic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nostalgic)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Feeling, evoking, or characterized by nostalgia.
>   *‘he remained nostalgic about the good old days’*
>   *‘a nostalgic account of an idyllic childhood’*